# Вимбачте, бумласка, дямкую ітд?

Tags: фонетика

Менѣ вѣдомі лише замѣни **в** на **м** як в [*мандрівник*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8#11536), або поширенѣша замѣна **н** на **м** перед губними, що є звичайним фолоноґічним явищем як [повна асімілація](//english.stackexchange.com/q/199077/226239). Однак **м** тут:

- додаїться, тобто поводиться як [епентеза](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0), хоча причин тому немає або так бачу;
- замѣнює нп. **дь** перед **л**, хоча і тут причин немає, бо **д** і **л** оба ~[ясенні](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82#%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%96_(%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%96)), тому недивно, що разом відносно часто зустрѣчаються в мовѣ: *для*, *бидло*, *бедлам*, *підло*, приростки на ***-д*** + слово на ***л-*** ітд. Навѣть якщо припустити, що ми повернули носовий в [*дѧка*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0#6016), то тут те саме: **н** ближча до **к** і теж тому відносно часта сполука: ***-н(-)*** + [дімінутівний](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0) наросток ***-ка***.

Пошуки нп. на Ґуґлѣ вказують, що таке явище поширене в соціяльних мережах, насамперед на Твітерѣ. Це точно не одруківка, бо **м**, крім того що додана окремо або замѣнює повністю декотрі букви, пак ще стоїть відносно віддалено від **л**, **дь**, **у**, **б** ітд. Тож це схоже на културний феномен, як мім. Хто, якщо це вѣдомо, перший так написав? Якщо це вплив іноміма, то якого? І які правила, якщо вони є, цього явища?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Це явно вплив англомовних мемів.

На форумі Wordreference є [обговорення](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/thamks.3611104/) на цю тему:

> […] *"thamks" is standard way to say when someone wants to be perceived as cute or if it is related to animals like dogs.*
>
> *People imagine animals as speaking a 'cute' or childish English.*
> *It's not surprising that people don't think of animals as being competent speakers of English (or any other language). They chose 'baby-talk' to represent animal speech because the image of animals as being childlike appeals to them.*

Коротко кажучи, люди вважають, що тварини не є кваліфікованими мовцями і роблять помилки. І ці помилки виглядають приємно, бо нагадують мовні помилки дітей.

Є і інші пояснення:

> ***thamks** — A backhanded, sarcastic way of attempting to apologize.*
> — [Urban Ditionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=thamk)

Наступні зображення показують, що `/m/, /w/` та інші звуки з'являються як у ролі епентези (*tha**m**ks*), так і метатези (*p**w**ease*):

[image: Мем 1] [image: Мем 2]

[image: Мем 3] [image: Мем 4]

Comment: То є так. До українськоѣ скорѣш за всього прибуло через мім [*doge cheems*](//knowyourmeme.com/memes/swole-doge-vs-cheems), котрий тут і наведений як Папа.

Comment: "m" та "n" там використовуються щоб показати, що вимова нечітка, невпевнена і "через ніс". Адже "n" та "m" - носові звуки. Тобто, епентеза, але зовсім.